# update password API rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

i am trying to check if the phn number starts with 0 the replace the 0 by 06, it works on console and also on password create but here in update password as code shown below it does not take any affect. i have no idea why.

```
  def update
# if @current_user.phone_num.start_with?('0') and !@current_user.phone_num.start_with?('00')
if @current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
  if @current_user.phone_num.start_with?('0')
    @current_user.phone_num =  @current_user.phone_num.sub!("0", "60")
  end
  if user_params[:avatar_uploader].present?
    @current_user.update(avatar: @current_user.avatar_uploader.url)
  end
  json_success('Successfully updated profile')
else
  json_bad_request("There were errors updating profile, #{@current_user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}", {errors: @current_user.errors.full_messages})
end
```

end

This is the api for update password. i hope anyone can help! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You never save it after modifying it.

Unrelated, but don't use `sub!` if you don't need to modify in place; use `sub`. In this case it shouldn't matter since you only do the substitution if it's required, but `sub!` returns `nil` if no substitutions are made–this can cause surprises if you're expecting the string back.

Comment: so should i do like " @current_user.save "

Comment: @bilal ... If you're not saving it currently, calling `save` certainly seems like a safe bet. Although if you're updating a single attribute, why not just use `update_attribute`? Or better yet, modify the phone param in-place and just do `update_attributes` and skip all the if statements? Or use very simple callbacks and take *all* of this out of the mainline code? This *definitely* doesn't belong in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save the phone num after substituting it. Better byebug into it to see if it saves successfully. From this line of code onwards:

```
    @current_user.phone_num =  @current_user.phone_num.sub!("0", "60")
    if @current_user.phone_num.save
      json_success('Successfully updated profile')
    else
      json_bad_request("There were errors updating profile, #{@current_user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}", {errors: @current_user.errors.full_messages})
    end
```

Agree with Dave, all that logic does not belong to the controller.

Comment: it does not add 60 to the number starting if the number starts with 0. and it gives json_bad_request error